# The .write command won't work on python

Tags: python-3.x

The .write function isn't working please help. I have gotten it to work before and it works once in my program but only with one document.

```
import os
file= open("path_to_file", 'r+')
text = input()
```

the next line of open has the variable as part of the path and is creating a new txt doc

```
test= open("bla/bla/bla/" + text + ".txt", 'a')
file.write("bla bla bla")
test.write("bla bla bla")
```

The txt documents stored as "file" when i open it the new text is there but with the text document stored as "test" when I open it there is no text. please help thank you.

Comment: I think you are not giving us all the relevant code.

Comment: What is your environment/IDE ? It is weird because your code doesn't seem to be a problem for me with Python 2.7.3 and `raw_input()`...

Comment: also tried with Python 3.3. Works fine. What are you hiding to us ? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all your help guys it turned out all i needed to do was:

```
test.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to close after writing :

```
test= open("bla/bla/bla/" + text + ".txt", 'a')
test.write("bla bla bla")
test.close()
```

This is always a good practice, if you don't the result can be quite randomized...

Comment: you should use `with` when possible

Comment: @Evan [this](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement). basically it guarantees closing the file.